# if statements in sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sms

Good morning all. I have an issue with a query. I want to select something in a query only if another field is somethingelse. The below query will better explain

```
select  
Case isnull(rl.reason,'Not Found')
  When 'D' then 'Discontinued'
  When 'N' then 'Not Found'
  When 'I' then 'Inactive'
  When 'C' then 'No Cost'
  When '' then 'Not Found'
End as Reason, ***If statement to select pv.descriptor only if reason is in ('D','I','C')***pv.descriptor
from table1 as rl
left join  table2 as v on v.field= rl.field


***Here i want an if statment to run if reason is in ('D','I','C')***
left join table3 as pv on 
Case rl.scantype
 when 'S' then cast(ltrim(rtrim(pv.field#1)) as varchar)
 when 'U' then cast(ltrim(rtrim(pv.field#2)) as varchar)
 when 'V' then cast(ltrim(rtrim(pv.vfield#3)) as varchar)
end
= rl.scan and pv.vend_no = rl.vendnum
***'**If statement ends*****

 left join storemain..prmastp as p on p.emuserid = rl.userid
 where rl.scandate between GetDate() -7 and GetDate() order by rl.scandate desc
```

I want the if statement to select the descriptor only if the reason selected is a 'D','I',or'C'. If not I want a null value there because i will not do the join to get that variable unless the reason is a 'D','I','C'

BY the way, I can used a case statement where i used it in the middle of the left join. It works perfectly fine. That's not my issue.

Comment: the query doesn't really better explain it.

Comment: You can't use CASE in SQL for control-of-flow.

Comment: So we've identified what's not the issue. What is the issue?

Comment: Your query states that you want to conditionally display pb.descriptor - however, there's no table aliased pb in the code. Do you mean pv.descriptor?

Comment: yes. sorry. I'll fix that.Thanks ED

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* that you want to only join to `pv` if `v.reason` is `(D, I, C)` - is that right? If that's your problem, just change your `JOIN` clause to:

```
LEFT JOIN table3 as pv ON 
   LTRIM(RTRIM(
       CASE rl.scantype
          WHEN 'S' THEN pv.field#1
          WHEN 'U' THEN pv.field#2
          WHEN 'V' THEN pv.field#3
       END
   )) = rl.scan 
   AND rl.vendnum = pv.vend_no
   AND rl.reason IN ('D', 'I', 'C')
```

Of course, you also have "If statement to select pv.descriptor only if reason is in ('D','I','C') [as] pv.descriptor" in the SELECT clause. So, assuming you want *that* instead, try this:

```
SELECT
   /* your other columns */
   CASE 
      WHEN rl.reason IN ('D', 'I', 'C') THEN pv.descriptor
      ELSE NULL --optional, since it'll default to NULL
   END as descriptor
```

Comment: I think this is my answer. +1, meanwhile.

Answer (score 2):

If you want it in one query, you HAVE to do the join. Using left joins and case statement as you have, you can ensure pv.descriptor is shown as null if that is what you want in certain cases.

If you want control flow, you will need to use T-SQL

If performance is your concern, you shouldn't be joining on computed values. Rethink the database design. You likey want to create new columns for your join, and may want to create intermediary tables if you have many-to-many relationships.

Answer (score 0):

What motivates the combination of two queries?  Joining could cause a radically different evaluation plan to be required... Selecting between two plans based on the values of variables (or worse - columns!) is not something the query optimizer does well.

You will be far better off if you write two queries and use a SQL IF statement to flow control to one of them.

Edit:  What should the query return if there are two rows from rl, one with reason=D and one with reason=S?

Comment: i edited the query. I put the wrong field name. A reason will never be 's' but scantype will be. Good observation though.

Answer (score 0):

I'd keep it simple so whoever supports your code in the future can figure out how to maintain it (when they add another reason code, for example).

It may not be as performant, but it's more maintainable.

Also, is there a way you can get those codes in a table and test for a marker, instead of having them hard-coded in sql?

Comment: The reason I am doing this is to make the query faster. I don't want the 'not found' scan numbers to be searched in table3 because table three has millions of records and it will search through them for nothing because that scan number won't be found(hence the data name). I can't do this in code because i am trying to avoid a build which right now is a long process to get code out to our other locations.

Comment: If you're trying to exclude those records before the join, you can do that without taking a non-standard approach.  I understand not using a lookup table is more performant, but the tradeoff is maintenance, and these codes are determined by the biz, not IT.

Comment: Also consider optimizing your approach for maintenance first, then performance.  Get the thing working to meet the biz requirements in the easiest to understand way possible, then optimize that code for performance.